# Redux store goes undefined despite successful initialization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I have a controller component "VideoManager" that renders a view component "Video". The view component renders a local video stream if one is available via props, otherwise it renders a button that initializes a video stream via getUserMedia (I've wrapped the getUserMedia API call in a promise. Looking at console logs, I see that the state is properly initialized as an empty Immutable Map. However, when I click the button, it appears the state becomes "undefined" before the promise completes, and thus throws an error 'Cannot read property 'getIn' of undefined'. Presumably this is because the state changes briefly before the promise completes (though I'm not sure why it'd go to undefined rather than staying in it's initial state).

Here is my controller component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import Video from './Video';
import bowser from 'bowser';
import * as actionCreators from '../action_creators';

export const VideoManager = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>
      <div>This is the VideoManager component.</div>
      <div>{bowser.chrome && bowser.version > 34 ? "Welcome!" : "Sorry, we only support Chrome version 34 and above"}</div>
      <Video {...this.props}/>
    </div>
  }
});

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return{
    localStreamURL: state.getIn(['localStreamInfo', 'localStreamURL'])
  };
}

export const VideoManagerContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, actionCreators)(VideoManager);
```

Here is my view component:

```
import React from 'react';

export default React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    const videoAndAudio = {audio: false, video: true};
    return <div>
      <div>This is the Video component.</div>
      {this.props.localStreamURL ? <video id="localVideo" src={this.props.localStreamURL}></video> : <button onClick={() => this.props.getLocalVideo(videoAndAudio)}>Get Local Video</button>}
    </div>
  }
});
```

My action creators:

```
export function getLocalVideo(config) {
  return {
    type: 'GET_LOCAL_VIDEO',
    config
  };
}
```

and my Reducer:

```
import {List, Map} from 'immutable';
import {createLocalStream} from './utils/webrtc_utils';

function getLocalVideo(state, config){
    createLocalStream(config).then(
    function(stream){    
        return state.set('localStreamInfo', Map({
            localStream: stream,
            localStreamURL: URL.createObjectURL(stream)
        }));
 }, function(err){
        console.log("Stream collection failed: ", err);
 });
}

export default function(state = Map(), action){
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'GET_LOCAL_VIDEO':
            return getLocalVideo(state, action.config);
    }
    return state;
}
```

Am I correct in my assumption that the promise is where this is getting derailed? If so how do I prevent 'connect' from telling the controller there is a new state before the promise is fulfilled?

**EDIT**
for posterity here is my promise-wrapped getUserMedia:

```
export function createLocalStream(callConfig){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;

        if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
           navigator.getUserMedia(callConfig,
              function(stream) {
                 resolve(stream);                
              },
              function(err) {
                 reject("The following error occured: " + err.name);
              }
           );
        } else {
           reject("getUserMedia not supported");
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing this:

```
export default function(state = Map(), action){
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'GET_LOCAL_VIDEO':
            return getLocalVideo(state, action.config);
    }
    return state;
}
```

While getLocalVideo is expected to return the new state, it isn't, which is why the state is undefined. You're modifying the state within your promise, which you should not be doing. Rather, try doing the async stuff within your 'getLocalVideo' function, calling actions for your different states (GET_LOCAL_VIDEO, GET_LOCAL_VIDEO_SUCCESS, GET_LOCAL_VIDEO_FAIL)

Something like this should work (don't forget to adapt your reducer)

```
export function getLocalVideo(config) {
  dispatch({type: 'GET_LOCAL_VIDEO', config});
  createLocalStream(config).then((stream)=>
      dispatch({
          type: 'GET_LOCAL_VIDEO_SUCCESS',
          localStreamInfo: Map({
              localStream: stream,
              localStreamURL: URL.createObjectURL(stream)
          })
      })
  }).catch((error)=>dispatch({type:'GET_LOCAL_VIDEO_FAIL', error}))
```

Comment: thanks quambo. should i move this getLocalVideo function to my action creators file instead or should it remain in reducer?

Comment: You've several options. 1. You could put it inside the action creator file (what most people would probably do). 2. You could put it into its own file (like /lib/local-stream.js) and import it in the action creator (which could be considered as the cleanest option). 3. You could put everything (actions types, actions and reducers) in one file like described here: https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux (which could be the most comfortable option)